# best practise to convert c# logic to f#

Tags: f#, f#-interactive, c#-to-f#, f#-data

So i have this as a script:

```
#r @"..\packages\FSharp.Data.2.4.2\lib\net45\FSharp.Data.dll"
#r "System.Xml.Linq.dll"

open FSharp.Data

// provide some URL, file path, or raw JSON sample
// that can be used at compile time to generate types
type Json = JsonProvider<"example.json">

// at runtime, load up new sample matching that schema
let response = Http.Request("https://world.openfoodfacts.org/api/v0/product/737628064502.json")
let samples = Json.Parse(response.Body.ToString())
```

What i want to do is this:

- Create an **extension**, that has a parameter of type: **Models.Product**, named *MyProduct*, which is available from a dll named *Models.dll*
- Add 2 extra parameters to the extension

  - *string language*
  - *string barcode*
- Update *MyProduct.Title* according to the received json file
- Return *MyProduct* with the updated data

Which in c# would be something like this:

```
public static Models.Product UpdateFromRemote(this Models.Product Product, string Language, string Barcode)
{
    //the f# code included above to fetch the remote source
    //only the url is fetched from:
    //  string.Format("https://{0}.openfoodfacts.org/api/v0/product/{1}.json",Language,Barcode);  

    Product.Title =  samples.Product.GenericName; //samples is the fetched resource from the f# code

    return Product;
}
```

What would be the logic in f#?

Currently i have this ( which is not correct/complete yet)

```
namespace LookupByBarcode.openfoodfacts.fSharp

open FSharp.Data

type model(Language,Barcode) = 
    member this.Language = Language
    member this.Barcode = Barcode

module getRemote = 
    type json = JsonProvider<"example.json">
        let response = json.Load("https://world.openfoodfacts.org/api/v0/product/737628064502.json")
            let Title = response.Product.ProductNameEn
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have an external DLL that you cannot modify that defines a type `Product`, then there is no easy way of adding new fields to the product. I think the most elegant F# way of doing this would be to wrap it in a record that adds the additional information:

```
type MyProduct = 
  { Product : Product
    Language : string
    Barcode : string }
```

Next, if you want to update a `MyProduct` value so that it reflects a newly obtained title, then it depends on what the underlying `Product` type looks like. Is it mutable or immutable?

To get idiomatic F# code, you would want to create a function that returns a clone. This is easy to do with F# records, but might be hard with C# objects. It might look something like this:

```
let updateProduct newTitle newLanguage myproduct =
  // Create a new `Product` with changed title. If you want to avoid mutation,
  // you need to create a new instance, which might be tedious for C# objects
  let op = myproduct.Product
  let np = 
    Product
      (Title = newTitle, OtherThing = op.OtherThing,
       YetAnotherThing = op.YetAnotherThing)

  // Now create a new updated F# record - this is much easier
  { myprodcut with Product = np; Language = newLanguage }
```

Working idiomatically with C# mutable objects in F# will be tricky, so my recommendation would be to define the domain model in F#, which will let you use the nice F# `with` keyword everywhere. That said, it might also make sense to just mutate the C# object - if that's what you really want to do.

Comment: Can you put the f# code on the appropriate place? I'd appreciate it for knowing what is correct/wrong logic

Comment: Perhaps a little logic mistake, the f# code is made for looking up a title, using a function with 2 parameters ( language and barcode). That code is "partial" in the f# class. The properties are already included on the Product model ( i only modify the Title property). Sorry if it wasn't clear